# Django's validation level

Tags: django

I have a model level validation:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # some fields

    def clean(self):
        pass
```

But how can I get a `request.user` in `clean` method so the model to be validated as via django's default admin forms as via views (REST api)?
Or what is the best practice in which level to validate: Model, ModelForm, Serializer, View?

Comment: You don't: models are request-unaware. That logic should be written in the view, or in a form where it will require some "tricks" to get the `request.user` in the form.

Comment: models are request-unaware. You should change way of your solution.

Comment: so what is the best way? I can write it in view but what about validation via Django's admin form? Need to duplicate?

Comment: @Mikhail: for the `ModelAdmin`, you will need to patch the object, you can do that with a mixin, see for example: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/pattern/set-values-to-a-created-updated-object-in-a-class-based-view.html (disclosure: I wrote that article).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem although that won't work for validation if the foreign key is not in the form since fields not in the form are excluded from validation, I have found that making the field disabled and hidden in the form to be a good solution to this problem (we would need to initialize the form with the user with either the `initial` kwarg or an unsaved instance).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: but hidden/disabled fields can be modified, it is not that hard to rewrite the DOM and make that field enabled. I know of a company five years ago where the telephone numbers of all customers and employees were leaked, because it used hidden form fields. One only had to provide the first character of the first name, and two for the last name, and one could, after selecting the person, simply inspect personal data.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem no values are submitted for a disabled field, also the form ignores the value even if they are submitted. What you say does apply if the field is _only_ hidden. Although that part about the leak is valid though and one should be careful what hidden fields are used, (but a foreign key should be somewhat safe here). See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#disabled

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: the `disabled` HTML attribute will not protect in any way, since one can "forge" a POST request, the disabled on a form indeed prevents it from altering. But regardless of that, it is still a way to expose data to the customer. Since now that customer knows all sorts of data, that a user should not know, of the user model, while typically that is something that you want to prevent. Usually it is better to limit the amount of data to the form to the bare minimum, especially since other it can be useful if there is a vulnerability elsewhere that can be exploited with that data.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem in that case we can only go for the somewhat hacky way of overriding [`_get_validation_exclusions` (GitHub)](https://github.com/django/django/blob/820408d842a07202a80e6ef7f7a57ec6258d88e6/django/forms/models.py#L316) and removing the relevant field from the returned list so that it is not `exclude`d from the form's validation (although again this feels a bit hacky).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: yes I agree, it might be better to *patch* the initial object first *before* the form validate, and then let the form do *all* validation. That would in fact be possible. We could make some `ProfileForm` that we start with `ProfileForm(instance=Profile(user=request.user))`, so then the object is already patched, and then the form can do full validation, instead of the current *ad hoc* method that only validates the specified fields.